# Error, type object has no attribute

Tags: python

Buenas quería consultar si alguno sabe resolver el error type object has no attribute

```py
arFiRubros = "C:\\sasa"
if not os.path.exists(arFiRubros):
    arLoRubros = open(arFiRubros, "w+b")
else:
    arLoRubros = open(arFiRubros, "r+b")

class Rubros:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombreRub = [None] * 3

for i in range (3):
    Rubros.nombreRub[i] = input("ingrese rubro ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque no creaste una instancia de la clase,
deberias de poner algo asi:

```
fooRubros = Rubros()
for i in range (3):
    fooRubros.nombreRub[i] = input("ingrese rubro")
```

Esto se debe a que cuando creas la instancia estás ejecutando la función **init**, creando a su vez un objeto tipo 'Rubros'.

Comment: y para mostrarlo como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Como es un atributo de la clase se comporta igual que una variable, puedes acceder a ella asi `fooRubros.nombreRub` y si quieres mostrala en consola `print(fooRubros.nombreRub)`